# Is it possible to detect central bluetooth devices?

Tags: sniffer

I'm trying to build a bluetooth presence system and I only can get peripheral devices.
I know that the peripheral devices are detectable because they send advertisement packets in broadcast, and the central device receives that packets and tries to establish a connection with them.

But is anyway to detect central devices too?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you would have a device to attempt to connect to them and then catalog the response.

Comment: I don't want to connect with any device.. I mean, I have a controller on an open field and I just want to scan if their is someone close that have the bluetooth enabled. I don't want to know if is central or peripheral you know